# how to \n in certain places in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

Trying to opening a new line in different points in a generated list.

ive tried to use this to seperate a list but it doesnt work.

```
for j in range (num,0,-1):
    for i in range(0,len(num),j):
        blist[i:j]
        print(blist)
```

heres my code

```
num=int(input('Size: '))
list=[]
blist=[]

for k in range(num,-1,-1):
    for i in range(0,num,1):
        list.append(i)
    num-=1
print(list)

for j in range (num,0,-1):
    for i in range(0,len(num),j):
        blist[i:j]
        print(blist)
```

heres the expected result

```
Size: 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0

Size: 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```py
n = int(input('Size: '))
L = [str(i) for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    print(' '.join(L[:n-i]))
```

Line by line explanation:

1. `L = [str(i) for i in range(n)]` Create a list of string digits from **0** up to **n-1**
2. `for i in range(n):` set **i** from **0** up to **n-1**
3. `L[:n-i]` slices the list `L` from start up  to `n-i` (not inclusive)
4. `' '.join(L[:n-i])` just *glues together* all the elements of the resulting slice with a white space `' '`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
num=int(input('Size: '))
list_=[]

for k in range(num,-1,-1):
    list_.append([str(i) for i in range(0,num,1)])
    num -= 1

result = '\n'.join([' '.join(l) for l in list_])
print(result)
```

The `result` takes each list in `list_` and joins them by a space, then the next join separates them by newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can work for me.

```
num=int(input('Size: '))
list_data = list(range(num))

for i in reversed(range(1, num +1 )):
    print( list_data[0:i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the output of `range` as arguments to `print` instead:

```
num = int(input('Size: '))
for n in range(num):
    print(*range(num - n))
```

Sample input/output:

```
Size: 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

Comment: This is very nice and clever!